# Using NavigationLink in ForEach loop in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, button, swiftui, navigation

I have a view that has a grid of buttons.  These buttons lead to another view, but depending on which button is pressed, passes in different information that will populate the view.  This is all already in a NavigationView.

```
ForEach(userData) { user in
    NavigationLink(destination: DestinationView(userData: user.data)) {
        Button(action: {}) {
            //button styling
        }
    }
}
```

The buttons display as intended and are clickable but nothing happens.  The subview is a giant black rectangle for testing and it does not appear.  I tried adding to each NavigationLink the isDetailLink(false) modifier, but that did not do anything.

Comment: `NavigationLink` and `Button` are usually exclusive of each other. In this case you just want what is clicked to lead to `DestinationView`, right? Is there a reason it *needs* to be a `Button`?

Comment: That worked.  That's interesting though -- I guess i was just trying to combine 2 different approaches from the internet.  Thanks.